# In C++, I can access private variables of a struct, but not the private variables within the sub-struct

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct teachers
{
    private:
        int gradDate;
        int quote;
        string name;
        string school;
        struct smallBoard
        {
            private:
                vector<string> grade;
                vector<string> school;
                vector<string> emblem;
                vector<int> year;
        };
        smallBoard sb;
    public:
        static void retrieveInformation(vector<teachers> &_teachers);
        static void t_addInfo(vector<teachers> &_teachers, teachers teachers_);
        static void s_addInfo(vector<teachers::smallBoard> &_smallBoard, teachers::smallBoard smallBoard_);
};
```

I can say

```
teachers tempt;  
tempt.name = "Bob";
```

but whenever I attempt to access any variable within the smallBoard struct it tells me its private. I'm assuming my method of accessing smallBoard is incorrect, so how would I accomplish that?

Comment: You need to show more code. Exactly where does the assignment to `tempt.name` happen?

Comment: GNU GCC. I just figured my issue out, answering in a second.

Comment: "...whenever I attempt to access..." Where is the code that "attempts to access"?

Answer (score 3):

Declaring `smallBoard` as a nested type inside of `teachers` does not change the fact that `smallBoard` is still its own data type with its own access rules.  In order for `teachers` to access private members of `smallBoard`, `teachers` must be declared as a `friend` of `smallBoard`.

```
struct smallBoard
{
private:
    vector<string> grade;
    vector<string> school;
    vector<string> emblem;
    vector<int> year;

    friend struct teachers;
};
```

Also, if `smallBoard` is declared as a `private` type of `teachers` then it cannot be used in parameters of public methods of `teachers`, since callers will never be able to access or instantiate `smallBoard` objects.  So you have to make `smallBoard` be public:

```
struct teachers
{
private:
    int gradDate;
    int quote;
    string name;
    string school;
    smallBoard sb;

public:
    struct smallBoard
    {
    private:
        vector<string> grade;
        vector<string> school;
        vector<string> emblem;
        vector<int> year;

    friend struct teachers;
    };

    static void retrieveInformation(vector<teachers> &_teachers);
    static void t_addInfo(vector<teachers> &_teachers, teachers teachers_);
    static void s_addInfo(vector<teachers::smallBoard> &_smallBoard, teachers::smallBoard smallBoard_);
};
```

Comment: Since the `struct` itself is private, why not just make its members public if you want to access them in the containing class?

Comment: @clcto: that would be true for the `smallBoard sb;` member of `teachers`, but since the `smallBoard` struct is also used in parameters of `teacher` public methods, `smallBoard` itself can't be private.

Answer (score -4):

```
struct smallBoard
{
    vector<string> grade;
    vector<string> school;
    vector<string> emblem;
    vector<int> year;
};

struct teachers
{
    private:
        int gradDate;
        int quote;
        string name;
        string school;
        smallBoard sb;
    public:
        static void retrieveInformation(vector<teachers> &_teachers);
        static void t_addInfo(vector<teachers> &_teachers, teachers teachers_);
        static void s_addInfo(vector<smallBoard> &_smallBoard, smallBoard smallBoard_);
};
```

I fixed it by separating the structs and defining one in my "main" struct. Compiles fine.

Comment: You "fixed" it by removing `private` access specifier from `smallBoard`. Which makes it completely unrelated to the original question. And if you did that, what was the point of pulling `smallBoard` out of `teachers`? I.e. your "separation" if the structs has nothing to do with the fix.

Comment: I apologize for not being a fluent coder, I'm just figuring things out as I go along.